# Android image slideshow, flip

Tags: android, image, flip

i saw few android apps got the interface similar with itune(as attached), user can search for the image by slide to left or right, and view the larger version by click on it. i try to find the example at google with few keywords like , `viewflipper, image slideshow... etc`,i was doing this for last 2 hours. result? none. :(

[image: itunes]

can someone give me a proper keyword how to do this on android? much appreciate  :)

Comment: Use **Gallery**. Search on Google. You will get so many examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called "CoverFlow" (yay, thanks Apple!). There is a widget on Google Code [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/) (I haven't tried it), or you can try [Googling it](https://www.google.ca/search?q=android+coverflow).

Answer (score 1):

Try via this keyword "coverflow". it help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try image carousel android keywords